# How to receive images from Jetson TX1 embedded camera?

Tags: opencv, webcam

I flashed my Jetson TX1 with the latest Jetpack (Linux For Tegra R23.2), and the following command works perfectly:

```
gst-launch-1.0 nvcamerasrc fpsRange="30.0 30.0" ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, format=(string)I420, framerate=(fraction)30/1' ! nvtee ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=(string)I420' ! nvoverlaysink -e
```

I tried to use the following python program to receive images from webcam:

source: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I got the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cvtColor, file /hdd/buildbot/slave_jetson_tx_2/35-O4T-L4T-Jetson-L/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3739
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webcam.py", line 11, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: /hdd/buildbot/slave_jetson_tx_2/35-O4T-L4T-Jetson-L/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3739: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

I know the problem is that it cannot receive images from webcam. I also changed the code to just show the received image from webcam, but it gives me error that means no image it get from camera.

I also tried to use C++ with the following code:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    VideoCapture cap;
    // open the default camera, use something different from 0 otherwise;
    // Check VideoCapture documentation.
    if(!cap.open(0))
        return 0;
    for(;;)
    {
          Mat frame;
          cap >> frame;
          if( frame.empty() ) break; // end of video stream
          imshow("this is you, smile! :)", frame);
          if( waitKey(1) == 27 ) break; // stop capturing by pressing ESC 
    }
    // the camera will be closed automatically upon exit
    // cap.close();
    return 0;
}
```

and it compiled without any errors using

```
g++ webcam.cpp -o webcam `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

But again, when I'm running the program I receive this error:

```
$ ./webcam
Unable to stop the stream.: Device or resource busy
Unable to stop the stream.: Bad file descriptor
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Bad file descriptor
Unable to stop the stream.: Bad file descriptor
```

What I've missed? Is there any command I should run to activate webcam before running this program?

Comment: Did you get any solution to this issue?

Comment: same problem here, do let us know if you came across a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the nvidia forums you need to get the gstreamer pipeline correct. And at the moment opencv can not autodetect the stream for the nvcamera.

The only way I got it to work, was with Opencv3 and this line of code to grab the video:

`cap = cv2.VideoCapture("nvcamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)640, height=(int)480, format=(string)I420, framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! video/x-raw, format=(string)I420 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR ! appsink")`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the information from this thread, anyway, I just got my python works to get one frame from TX1 camera module.

The important thing to get it work is that we need install OpenCV 3.1.0, you can follow the official build method and replace python cv2.so lib to version 3.1.0. Original l4t OpenCV is 2.4.

And the other important thing is to use correct nvcamerasrc; try
c

```
ap = cv2.VideoCapture("nvcamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=(int)1920, height=(int)1080, format=(string)I420, framerate=(fraction)30/1 ! nvtee ! nvvidconv flip-method=2 ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), format=(string)I420 ! nvoverlaysink -e ! appsink")
```

It works on my TX1, just for sharing here.